# C - Wrong printed values on a matrix

Tags: c, arrays, matrix

So I created a program that generates a random 4x4 matrix, with values ranging from 0 to 17. Afterwards, it would calculate and print the sum of each rows and columns. The problems are, (1) values of row sums are incorrect, (2) the last element, which is the `m[4][4]`, seems to double in value, giving an incorrect value for the sum of Column 4 as well. Here is the code:

```c
srand(time(NULL));

printf("Generating matrix... ");
getch();
printf("\n\n");

for (i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
    for (j = 1; j <= 4; j++) {

        m[i][j] = rand() % 17;
        printf("%d\t", m[i][j]);

        if (i == 1) {                          //  Calculation of Row Sums
            rSum[1] += m[i][j];
        } else if (i == 2) {
            rSum[2] += m[i][j];
        } else if (i == 3) {
            rSum[3] += m[i][j];
        } else if (i == 4) {
            rSum[4] += m[i][j];
        }

        if (j == 1) {                        //  Calculation of Column Sums
            cSum[1] += m[i][j];
        } else if (j == 2) {
            cSum[2] += m[i][j];
        } else if (j == 3) {
            cSum[3] += m[i][j];
        } else if (j == 4) {
            printf("\n");
            cSum[4] += m[i][j];
        }
    }
}

getch();
printf("\n\n");

for (i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {                  //  Printing of Values

    printf("Sum of Row %d: %d\n", i, rSum[i]);
    printf("Sum of Column %d: %d\n", i, cSum[i]);
    printf("-----------------------------------------------\n");
}

return 0;
```

Comment: @ EruelSantos When your question is solved, you should click the check mark next to the answer that helped you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Arrays are `0` based in C.  You should change all your loops to iterate this way:

```
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
```

And also change other parts of your code where you use explicit index values.  This part can be simplified drastically.

The arrays `rSum` and `cSum` must be initialized to `0`.  Failure to do it might explain the incorrect values computed by your program.

Here is an improved version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    int m[4][4];
    int rSum[4] = { 0 };
    int cSum[4] = { 0 };
    int i, j;

    srand(time(NULL));

    printf("Generating matrix... ");
    getch();
    printf("\n\n");

    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            m[i][j] = rand() % 17;
            printf("%d\t", m[i][j]);

            rSum[i] += m[i][j];    //  Calculation of Row Sums
            cSum[j] += m[i][j];    //  Calculation of Column Sums
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    getch();
    printf("\n\n");

    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {         //  Printing of Values
        printf("Sum of Row %d: %d\n", i, rSum[i]);
        printf("Sum of Column %d: %d\n", i, cSum[i]);
        printf("-----------------------------------------------\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```